# sparse matrix matrix multiplication in python for rectangular matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am working in python with sparse matrix A of size n x m.
I am using csr_matrix format from scipy and I am wrapping my matrix to be linearoperator, so I could use slinalg package.

I need to compute A^T*A product. However, I can not manage to find proper routine to achieve this.
I could use matmat function of linearoperator, but this requires me to convert matrix to dense format.

Is there any way how could I multiply two sparse matrices in python (even with different package) without converting to dense matrix? My matrices are big and conversion causes crash due to memory requirements.

Comment: Is your `*T` another mumltiplication or transpose?  `Sparse has transpise, and  also matrix muliplication.  Don't just skim its docs.

Comment: The closure reason is wrong.  This isn't an open ended recommendation question.  The "even with different package" phrase is parenthetical.  Matrix multiplication is built into the sparse package that he is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SciPy` has very efficient built-in method for matrix multiplication of '*sparse* *csr_matrix*' without converting it into dense matrix.

You can directly use the following:

```
import scipy

data, row, column = ...
A = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, column)), shape = (...))

matmul = A.T*A
```

Comment: thanks! for some reason, I understood that this was pointwise mat mat multiplication, not standard mat mat multiplication

Comment: `A.multiply(A)` is the pointwise multiplication.  `*`, `@` and `dot` all do matrix multiplication.  `*` is pointwise for dense `ndarray`, but this is a different class (modeled more on the `np.matrix` class).